# GCM and Google Analytics integration together in google-services.json file using different google account?

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-cloud-messaging

I have to integrate GCM and Google Analytics in same app.so first we need to get the `google-services.json` configuration file for that.well, assume that i have two google a/c. imagine it as **gcm@gmail.com** and **analytics@gmail.com**.i need to create google anaytics property using **analytics@gmail.com** and Google Cloud Messaging configuration using **gcm@gmail.com** so how i can make the `google-services.json` file for that ? I know to create it using same google account for both GCM & Analytics but ain't aware about the scenario i have explained.someone help me out please.you can see below i have generated Google Analytics configuration file using one a/c, now i have to merge the details of GCM to the json.how it can be as the gmail a/c is different ?

```
{
  "project_info": {
    "project_id": "xx-xx",
    "project_number": "xxx",
    "name": "xx"
  },
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:xxxxxx:xxxxx:xxxxxxx",
        "client_id": "android:xx.xx.xx",
        "client_type": 1,
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "xx.xx.xx"
        }
      },
      "oauth_client": [],
      "api_key": [],
      "services": {
        "analytics_service": {
          "status": 2,
          "analytics_property": {
            "tracking_id": "UA-xxxxxxxx-x"
          }
        },
        "cloud_messaging_service": {
          "status": 1,
          "apns_config": []
        },
        "appinvite_service": {
          "status": 1,
          "other_platform_oauth_client": []
        },
        "google_signin_service": {
          "status": 1
        },
        "ads_service": {
          "status": 1
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "client_info": [],
  "ARTIFACT_VERSION": "1"
}
```

Comment: There isn't anything about this kind of setup in the documentation so I think this is not possible as of the moment.

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35014978/27150730)

Comment: I wonder did you find a solution for this?