# How to integrate two or more google-services.json file together for different google service in same project using Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services

I am making a project where I want to integrate `GCM` and `Google sign in` but the problem is both have `google-services.json` configuration file which we need to add in our project.

> So, how can I integrate both `google-services.json` configuration
>   file in my project.

Here is my one of the configuration file

```
{
  "project_info": {
    "project_id": "default-xxx",
    "project_number": "xxx",
    "name": "xxx"
  },
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:xxx",
        "client_id": "x.package",
        "client_type": 1,
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "x.package_name"
        }
      },
      "oauth_client": [],
      "api_key": [],
      "services": {
        "analytics_service": {
          "status": 1
        },
        "cloud_messaging_service": {
          "status": 1,
          "apns_config": []
        },
        "appinvite_service": {
          "status": 1,
          "other_platform_oauth_client": []
        },
        "google_signin_service": {
          "status": 1
        },
        "ads_service": {
          "status": 1
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "client_info": [],
  "ARTIFACT_VERSION": "1"
}
```

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34942242/gcm-and-google-analytics-integration-together-in-google-services-json-file-using?rq=1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34942242/gcm-and-google-analytics-integration-together-in-google-services-json-file-using?rq=1)

Comment: @Md- doesn't have any solution on that post also

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally I have done it as follows:

**Step1:** Open your desired google service page in my case its [google sign in](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating) and [GCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client). There will be a button saying **Get configuration file**, click on that and input your details and get the configuration files.

**Step2:** Check both of the configuration file it would have same configuration in **`project_info`** object and **`client_info`** object. The difference would be in **`services`** object where you have to check for status if you have added two or more service the **status** value would be **`2`** which means they are enabled services. You can see in below configuration file which I have generated for two of the services which is **Google sign in** and **GCM**.

You just have to check your **status** values in **services** object where it is saying **2** for all the services you have integrated in your project is the configuration file you have to add.

```
{
  "project_info": {
    "project_id": "xxxxxxxxxx",
    "project_number": "xxxxxxxx",
    "name": "xxxxxxxxxxx"
  },
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
        "client_id": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
        "client_type": 1,
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "xxxxxxxxxx"
        }
      },
      "oauth_client": [
        {
          "client_id": "xxxxxxxxxx",
          "client_type": 1,
          "android_info": {
            "package_name": "xxxxxxxx",
            "certificate_hash": "xxxxxxxxxxx"
          }
        }
      ],
      "api_key": [],
      "services": {
        "analytics_service": {
          "status": 1
        },
        "cloud_messaging_service": {
          "status": 2, <======= this is my gcm service status
          "apns_config": []
        },
        "appinvite_service": {
          "status": 1,
          "other_platform_oauth_client": []
        },
        "google_signin_service": {
          "status": 2   <===== this my google sign in service status
        },
        "ads_service": {
          "status": 1
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "client_info": [],
  "ARTIFACT_VERSION": "1"
}
```

**Note:** I am using **Google sign in** service so its generating **oauth_client** field value also which you wouldn't get if you generate only for **GCM**.

Answer (score 5):

You do not need two different google-services.json files. Both will have identical configurations. These configuration files are unique for every project irrespective of how many services you have activated.

Prior generating the configuration file, ensure you have activated both the services. The generated configuration file will be valid for both.

Follow the "Continue to Sign In" link that appears below the "Download and install Configuration" link for documentation regarding what to do next.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, there some changes in configuration files regarding status of the services which you have to look on when you are creating for two or more google services

Comment: As you keep adding services, the google-services.json gets updated. So the last file you download has all services activated.

Comment: Yeah I got it and I have posted my solution with the some changes which I have done.

Comment: For any future readers, there are cases where you need 2 different, as in modified versions of your google-services.json, ie. for flavors with different package_name attributes.