# Multiple Google Configuration Service

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

I am using two Google services in my app. Both the services are created/registered with two different email addresses.

`Google cloud Messaging` - a@gmail.com.
`Google Analytics` - b@gmail.com

Now I came to know about Google Configuration `JSON` files. Can we have multiple files in the same project where different services can refer to different files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already answered in [How to integrate two or more google-services.json file together for different google service in same project using Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35012700/how-to-integrate-two-or-more-google-services-json-file-together-for-different-go/35014978#35014978), you do not need two different google-services.json files. Both will have identical configurations. These configuration files are unique for every project irrespective of how many services you have activated.

With reference to getting a configuration file for [Google Cloud Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client#get-config) and [Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/#get-config), wherein you must select an existing project for your app, it shows that both have identical `google-services.json` file.

And as noted, as you keep adding services, the `google-services.json` file gets updated. The last file you download has all the services activated.