# How to add use different google-services.json in one project?

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, google-play-services, firebase-analytics

I have integrated Firebase Crashlytics, Analytics, and Messaging. This means I have imported google-services.json from Firebase to my Android project.

Now I want to further leverage my data from Firebase Analytics to Google Analytics. This requires separate Android and iOS setup, which means I need to import another google-services.json from Google Analytics to my Android project.

How can I achieve this?

I have read about [How to add two google-services.json files in same project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40255208/1968739) and [How to use a Different google-services.json file with multiple Product flavors — Android](https://medium.com/android-news/how-to-use-different-google-services-json-file-with-multiple-product-flavors-android-7853d98dd6c0) but I don't think it applies to my situation.