# how can i use two google-service.json file in one project

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-platform, oauth

I'm developing a flutter project, and I need firestore, so I connected my project to firebase, and google-services.json file was automatically created in my flutter project. But I have a problem, I can use firebase to implement google login, but I don't want to, so I created an OAuth client directly from google cloud platform. In the process, I got one more google-services.json file, which I need to register, but I don't know what to do with it since I already have a google-services.json file from firebase. If you have experience with this, I hope you can help me.

I've been searching related information around, but all I'm finding is stuff about how to connect two Firebase projects which is not my case

Answer (score 0):

According to the answer of Mr **Frank van Puffelen** from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40255208/how-to-add-two-google-services-json-files-in-same-project#:%7E:text=There%20is%20no,json%20going%20forward.):

It is not possible to use two google-services.json files in a single app. The file name is the same between them, and they need to be in the same location, so one will overwrite the other in that case.

> However, the google-services.json file is auto-parsed when you create a `FirebaseApp`. You can also explicitly specify the information needed for a `FirebaseApp` in your code. By doing so, you can access two Firebase projects from a single app. Another option would be to manually merge the two google-services.json files, but this is not recommended as you may overwrite the manually merged file with a new version at some point.
>
> The final option, and the recommended one, is to migrate the files from the older Firebase project to the new one. This way, you'll only need one google-services.json going forward.

If you need to integrate with multiple Firebase projects, you can support multiple environments in your  application by organizing the google-services.json files in dedicated directories named for each variant under the app module root. This allows you to have different google-services.json files for different build variants.

While it's not possible to use two google-services.json files simultaneously, you can work with multiple Firebase projects by organizing the files in dedicated directories and explicitly specifying the Firebase configuration in your code.