# google-service json multiple json or configuration

Tags: android, firebase

I am currently adding a feature to an existing app. This app uses a Google sign-in with gms NOT firebase. the app have a `google-service.json` file with the app with a project id and number associated to a project stored on a google cloud platform.

Now I have to integrate a new tool using firebase for messaging. firebase configuration also provides a `google-service.json` specific to this firebase project.

My question is: is it possible to load 2 different `google-service.json` ? I have a feeling that not due to the project_id/name. Is it possible to merge both to one but i do not think that the json can contain more than 2 projects.

I know that we can have multiple `google-service.json` for the different variant but in my case it's 2 files for each variant.

google cloud platform:

```
{
  "project_info": {
    "project_number": "289537605704",
    "project_id": "xxx-yyy-bbb-1055"
  },
  "client": [
```

firebase one:

```
{
  "project_info": {
    "project_number": "149940006325",
    "firebase_url": "https://xxx.firebaseio.com",
    "project_id": "xxx-android-app",
    "storage_bucket": "xxx-android-app.appspot.com"
  },
  "client": [
```

In that casem do I have to move everything on one single project on firebase ?

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK there is no need of using two json files. Json file which you get from firebase is enough iff you have given same package name(same as in google console project) while creating firebase project too. If it consufes you then I would suggest to use Google sign-in of firebase and use google json of firebase. But I think firebase will create OAuth client in Google platform when u enable google login in firebase by itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How it works is -

1. You use the same Google account for logging in into both Firebase console and Google developers console.
2. Create a project in Google developers console for adding Google SignIn to your app. Configure the package name and add the SHA1 key and it will give you a **google-services.json** file to download. Ignore this downloaded file. Just keep it with you if needed in future.
3. Go to Firebase console, use the same project that you had setup while adding Google SignIn in the Google developers console add whatever Firebase service you need in the Firebase console.
4. Now when you download the **google-services.json** file in the Firebase console, it will have credentials of all the service you are using in that project including the Google SignIn that you had added in the Google developers console.
   Just use this **google-services.json** file in your project.

Or

Just simply do one thing if you can. Just login to Firebase console. You can add your Google login (Firebase auth) and Firebase messaging from there itself. It in the the end just download the **google-services.json** file there itself which will have credentials of all the Firebase services you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, u have to move both in firebase, as project and client info should be same for both json files, only service info would change. There is a similar question already asked here 
[Stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35012700/how-to-integrate-two-or-more-google-services-json-file-together-for-different-go)